# re.sub() doesn't replace middle of string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to replace the contents of brackets in a string with nothing. The code I am using right now is like this:

```
 tstString = "OUTPUT:TRACK[:STATE]?"  
 modString = re.sub("[\[\]]","",tstString)
```

When I print the results, I get:

```
OUTPUT:TRACK:STATE?
```

But I want the result to be:

```
OUTPUT:TRACK?
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You only remove `[` and `]` with your regex. Use `r'\[[^][]*]'`

Comment: thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I guess this one will work fine. Regexp now match Some string Inside `[]`. Not `?` after `*`. It makes * non-greedy

```
import re
tstString = "OUTPUT:TRACK[:STATE]?"  
modString = re.sub("\[.*?\]", "", tstString)
print modString
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expression `"[\[\]]"` says 'any of these characters: "[", "]"'.

But you want to delete what's between the square brackets too, so you should use something like `r"\[:\w+\]"`. It says '[, then :, then one or more alphanumeric characters, then ]'.

And please, always use raw strings (`r` in front of quotes) when working with regular expressions to avoid funny things connected with Python string processing.

Comment: @mata, I'm terribly sorry, I feel that formatting migth have eaten some of your comment. Just to clarify, do you mean that `r'[\[\]]'` matches backslashes as well as square brackets?

Comment: my mistake, I've mixed something up